# hokuyo error 06->06

Tags: ros, lidar, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im using a hokuyo urg-04lx , and whenever i run hokuyo_node i get this error

Exception thrown while opening Hokuyo.
timeout reached (in hokuyo::laser::laserReadline) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting

and

Laser returned abnormal status message, aborting: Trouble!! Error Code=[06->06] You may be able to find further information at http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting/

is there any solution ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28173/hokuyo-error-06-%3E06/) by [vivek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1350/vivek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/11150/hokuyo_node-error-code-15-15) and the [SCIP 2.0 protocol](http://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/data/URG_SCIP20.pdf) (page 11), it looks like this is the Scan Interval has non-numeric value.

Can you verify your Hokuyo still works with the Hokuyo tools?  Can you hear it spinning?  Is it making bad noises?

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vivek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1350/vivek/) on 2012-02-22**:
i tried reconnecting and found something odd, it kept spinning up and spinning down and again spinning up and continues this for about 6 times and then stops. i tried with hokuyo tools , but it dosent even recognise the laser. Im having a feeling that this is a hardware problem.

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2012-02-23**:
Sorry to hear that.  :(